# Bootstrap datepicker auto collapse when click different id

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have the following code:

```html
<input type="text" value="2014-10-13" class="input-small datepicker" id="beginDate">
<input type="text" value="2014-10-13" class="input-small datepicker" id="endDate">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#beginDate').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(){
       $('#beginDate').datepicker('hide');
    });
    $('#endDate').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(){
       $('#endDate').datepicker('hide');
    });
</script>
```

I've followed this [tutorial](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) and had success to collapse datepicker when datachange or an user clicks outside of datepicker panel, but I have problem to auto collapse datepicker when user click on `endDate` then directly click on `beginDate`.

It's something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kmbo576p/), although I don't use same source.

The datepicker `beginDate` just in top of datepicker `endDate` (endDate datepicker not collapse) but in abode link it's not happen (able to collapse automatically).

I've tried to modify my script like this:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#beginDate').datepicker()
       .on('show', function() {
          $('#endDate').datepicker('hide');
       });
       .on('changeDate', function(){
          $('#beginDate').datepicker('hide');
        });
    $('#endDate').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(){
       $('#endDate').datepicker('hide');
    });
</script>
```

But it mess everything. Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

use following code :

```
$('#beginDate').datetimepicker();
$('#endDate').datetimepicker();
```

Have a look at this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kmbo576p/571/